# Highcharts - nested sliced donut charts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to create a nested pie / donut chart, where the inner ring displays a 'group' (e.g. a car manufacturer) and the outer ring displays a breakdown for that 'group' (e.g. the models made by each manufacturer).

I need the individual segments to be exploded / sliced so that it looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdGRn.jpg

I have managed to get this working using the `sliced` and `slicedOffset` properties (the image above is actually a screenshot of my chart), however this creates strange effects (see the fiddle) when there are fewer 'groups'.

I have put together a fiddle to demonstrate how the chart looks odd when there are fewer groups in the inner ring. It looks really bad when there are only one or two items in the inner ring:

http://jsfiddle.net/danielcrisp/784jzLe2/

I would like to know if there is a better way of achieving the result I require? Probably `sliced` is not the right way to go as it isn't its intended use. How else can I get a gap between items?

**Note:** the chart will be displayed over a photo so I can't use borders to create the effect.

**Update:** It's ok if the spacing between segments is regular, e.g. 10px, unlike the irregular spacing shown in the first screenshot.

Transparent borders *should* be the perfect solution but they don't mask the segment fill colour unfortunately.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add some dummy data points that will be transparent. This solution will need some calculations for good visual results.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/25acys4j/4/

Example of transparent slice:

```
{x: 0,
 y: 3,
 color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)'
},
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this is as close as I can get... it's not perfect but it will have to do for now

Answer (score 0):

Try to adapt donut chart, and border like this: http://jsfiddle.net/25acys4j/. The border can get a transparent color, when you define it as `rgba();`

Comment: Transparent borders don't seem to be visible. Here is the example with a yellow background and you'll see the borders become invisible, so there is no spacing: http://jsfiddle.net/danielcrisp/25acys4j/1/